# How can i add required field while creating a form?

Tags: jquery, laravel

This is my code :

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label">Mobile Number:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, ['type' => 'number', 'min' => 0, 'id' => 'mobile', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Eg: 9876543210', 'tabindex' => 15]) !!}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here i want to give this mobile number field as required, how can i add it in my code?
And i am having 3 steps in the creation of form and i am having mobile number in step1, when i am clicking the next button without adding mobile number, it should display an alert message..Now it is displaying alert message of mobile field required, only after clicking submit button in last step (i.e) in step 3..

Comment: Try this: `{{ Form::text('key', 'value', ['required']) }}`

Comment: Or do this: ` 'required' => ''` in your [ ] parameter list.

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali, its not working..

Comment: You could add some `javascript` to check validation when the user click next button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check it with your `next_button` using `jquery`

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label class="control-label">Mobile Number:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      {!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, ['type' => 'number', 'min' => 0, 'id' => 'mobile', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'Eg: 9876543210', 'tabindex' => 15]) !!}

    <button style="margin-right:20px;" class="next_button btn btn-info active nextBtn btn-md pull-right" type="next" >Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.next_button').click(function(event){
        if ($('#mobile').val() == ""){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Enter the number');
        }
    });
});
```

Added `next_button` class in your existing code

Comment: <button style="margin-right:20px;" class="btn btn-info active nextBtn btn-md pull-right"  type="next" >Next</button>

Comment: Not bad.., Now it displays alert, but when we click OK in that alert, it moves to next step and not allowing to enter our mobile number..

Comment: It's probably because you have class "next_button" which shouldn't let you to next step and class nextBtn which probably lets you to next step. Where is code for that button for next step? If it's also in Javascript then add this code before it navigates you to step 2

Answer (score 2):

Add `'required' => true` to the array:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'mobile',  null, ['required' => true, 'type' => 'number'....
```

Comment: @ManiRajMurugan do you get any error or something? What is HTML output?

Comment: @ManiRajMurugan I'm pretty sure this error is not related to the code in my answer.

Comment: It also bring out the error like this,
   "An invalid form control with name='mobile' is not focusable."